# c++ strict aliasing problem --- driving me crazy

Tags: c++, unions, strict-aliasing

Okay... I'm getting kind of desperate trying to get this code to work with strict aliasing turned on (and -O3).
I was unable to shorten the code down (sry...) so it's fairly long ~170 lines...

```
struct S
{
    enum
    {
        leaf,
        node
    } type; // the type of the structure. leaf means has a value. node has vector.

    union
    {
        int value;
        std::vector<struct S*> *v;
    } data; // the data. only one is active dependant on the type
};

//compares two structs
bool cmpStructs( const struct S *s1, const struct S *s2 );
//compares the 'top levels' i.e. type and if leaves then also the value
bool cmpStructs1( const struct S *s1, const struct S *s2 );

int main( void )
{
    // Create the structure: s1 = [1,2] s2 = [1,3]. Just some random stuff
    struct S *s1 = new struct S;
    struct S *s2 = new struct S;

    s1->type = s2->type = S::node;

    s1->data.v = new std::vector<struct S*>( 2U );
    s2->data.v = new std::vector<struct S*>( 2U );

    struct S *t = new struct S;
    t->type = S::leaf;
    t->data.value = 1;
    s1->data.v->front() = t;

    t = new struct S;
    t->type = S::leaf;
    t->data.value = 2;
    s1->data.v->back() = t;

    t = new struct S;
    t->type = S::leaf;
    t->data.value = 1;
    s2->data.v->front() = t;

    t = new struct S;
    t->type = S::leaf;
    t->data.value = 3;
    s2->data.v->back() = t;

    //compare s1 and s2. Note: the result is actually not important. the problem is the crash.
    if( cmpStructs( s1, s2 ) )
        std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "not equal" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

bool cmpStructs( const struct S *s1, const struct S *s2 )
{
    // compare 'top-level'
    if( cmpStructs1( s1, s2 ) == false )
        return false;
    // i.e. s1->type == s2->type and s1->value == s2->value
    if( s1->type != S::node )
        return true;
    // different vector sizes don't compare the same
    if( s1->data.v->size() != s2->data.v->size() )
        return false;
    // used to iterate over all elements in the tree structure of struct S
    struct const_iteratorList
    {
        std::vector<struct S*>::const_iterator it, end;
        struct const_iteratorList *next, *previous;
    } l1, l2, *c1, *c2;

    c1 = &l1;
    c2 = &l2;

    bool equal = true;

    c1->it = s1->data.v->begin();
    c1->end = s1->data.v->end();

    c2->it = s2->data.v->begin();
    c2->end = s2->data.v->end();

    c1->previous = c2->previous = c1->next = c2->next = NULL;

    do
    {
        while( c1->it != c1->end )
        {// This is where it crashes. Though basically the same stuff as above
            if( cmpStructs1( *(c1->it), *(c2->it) ) == false )
            {
                equal = false;
                break;
            }

            if( (*(c1->it))->type != S::node )
            {
                ++(c1->it);
                ++(c2->it);
                continue;
            }

            if( (*(c1->it))->data.v->size() != (*(c2->it))->data.v->size() )
            {
                equal = false;
                break;
            }
            // since *(c1->it) is not a leaf we need to look into its subnodes
            c1->next = new struct const_iteratorList;
            c2->next = new struct const_iteratorList;

            c1->next->it = (*(c1->it))->data.v->begin();
            c1->next->end = (*(c1->it))->data.v->end();

            c2->next->it = (*(c2->it))->data.v->begin();
            c2->next->end = (*(c2->it))->data.v->end();

            c1->next->previous = c1;
            c2->next->previous = c2;
            c1 = c1->next;
            c2 = c2->next;

            c1->next = c2->next = NULL;
        }

        if( c1->previous != NULL )
        {
            c1 = c1->previous;
            c2 = c2->previous;

            delete c1->next;
            delete c2->next;

            ++(c1->it);
            ++(c2->it);
        } else
            break;
    } while( equal == true );

    while( c1->previous != NULL )
    {
        c1 = c1->previous;
        c2 = c2->previous;

        delete c1->next;
        delete c2->next;
    }

    return equal;
}

bool cmpStructs1( const struct S *s1, const struct S *s2 )
{
    if( s1->type == S::node )
    {
        if( s2->type == S::node )
            return true;
    } else
    {
        if( s2->type == S::node )
            return false;

        if( s1->data.value == s2->data.value )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The problem is easily described: It works without -fstrict-aliasing and breaks with it.
with 'breaks' I mean 'crashes'.
Please help me get it to work in both cases :P
Thanks!!! in advance (I've tried for some hours...)

EDIT:
It crashes.
Basically I have no idea of what could be wrong so I have tried to narrow things down by taking away code paths and retrying... But it didn't take me anywhere.

EDIT: added some comments

Comment: Could you tell everyone exactly which part is not working, and also what you have tried so far?

Comment: It crashes at the cmpStructs1 call in the while loop

Comment: Please provide the complete program source, including headers. Also, what version of g++ are you using? What command-line arguments are you building with? On my system (Ubuntu 11.04, g++ 4.5.2, command lines: `g++ -O4 -Wall -Werror -fstrict-aliasing -o sa1 sa.cc` and `g++ -O4 -Wall -Werror -fno-strict-aliasing -o sa2 sa.cc`), the two programs produce identical results: `not equal`.

Comment: `new struct const_iteratorList;`? Odd....

Comment: I'm using Apples gcc 4.2 in XCode 4.0.1.

Comment: Although I haven't reviewed the code it compiles, runs and doesn't crash for me with gcc 4.4.4. valgrind reports two memory leaks but no obvious problems such as reads from uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Billy I need to avoid recursion in my code because of potential stack overflows. That is wy I need to put everything on the heap.

Comment: @Charles yeah. I didnt include the delete stuff because it didnt matter for the example... But why on earth does it work for you and not me?!

Comment: @Rob: `-O4` does nothing that `-O3` doesn't. In fact, if you look at the g++ source code, you will see that the check looks something like: `if(level >= 3) { /* apply level 3 optimizations */ }`

Comment: Okay I'm building GCC 4.6.1 now... Maybe tomorrow I can be blessed with working object code then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a bug. It works with GCC 4.6.1. Just want to close the question...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a question: why would you place an `int` and a `vector<int>*` in a union? That makes both members of the union share the same memory (i.e. updating `value` overwrites `v` and vice versa).

It looks to me like you'd rather be using a struct:

```
struct
{
    int value;
    std::vector<struct S*> *v;
} data;
```

This lays the objects sequentially in memory (i.e. `v` is now *after* `value`, as opposed to "on top of" `value`).

Also, in this case, you may wish to just use a normal vector, as you don't have the restriction on unions anymore:

```
struct
{
    int value;
    std::vector<struct S*> v;
}
```

But that's up to you.

### Edit

As per Billy's comment, you can also keep things simpler and make the struct nice and flat:

```
struct S
{
    enum
    {
        leaf,
        node
    } type;

    int value;
    vector<S*> *v
};
```

Comment: Or just not put things in a separate `struct` or `union` to begin with. I think the reason he's using a `union` is to avoid having to have space for the `int` and `vector`.... though I think it's a premature optimization...

Comment: No. Actually I want the union because it saves space. I'm sorry I didn't comment my code at all... This case is a very stripped down example of some 20k loc sources over 50+ files which makes extensive use of these structures. The 'type' field is the 'tag' of the union.

Comment: Aaahh, I get it now - I thought you were attempting to store data at each node. I'm off to school now, but I'll keep thinking about your problem in case no one else gets to it. Reading some of the other comments, it looks like your code *may* in fact be valid. I'll check into it further once my commute is over.

Comment: @iolo: The potential space you save there is lost many times over when you do a dynamic allocation of the `vector`, which is typically at least `4*sizeof(int)` per application. (Remember, the memory manager has tracking stuff whenever you allocate memory to worry about too)

Comment: @Billy Well... yes... First: I always save space when I can. Second: the real world code doesnt use an int as the value type but rather a structure that is 3-4 (depending on the system) *sizeof(int) making for a fine justification ;)

Comment: I won't complain about the design too much - I've seen the same idea used in so many places. Heck, now I want to do my own!

Comment: @iolo: Not really. You're saving `3-4*sizeof(int)` in your structure, at the expense of `3-4*sizeof(int)` (at least... more on x64 platforms) in the heap manager. You've also made the code a lot more complicated, and limited parallelism of your code due to having to rely on locks in the heap manager. Unless you can show that you have memory pressure problems or something like that, this kind of optimization should wait. And in this case I suspect it's a pessimization. I'd probably be waiting until the other data was at least 8ish`*sizeof(int)` before using this kind of trick.

Comment: @Billy The added code complexity is hardly visible. In the code I would have to do the typechecking (leaf or node) anyway (actually there is 1 more with a special meaning) and an extra 'data.' is not killing me. Hm... you think that would induce an extra time penalty. I will have to look closer into that. If it really gets better then I owe you something :D (But changing that code is not going to be fun :S)